# Accessing subView from View Controller without extra delegates

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a "View Controller" and a "Main View", now I have a "child view" that creates a custom view that returns a switch and a label related to that, and I add several of these custom views to my Main View. My question : Is there anyway possible to set button target and access these child views with only setting the delegate in parent View? or each of them needs it own delegate?

child View:

```
import UIKit


class RowView: UIView {
  var title: String
  var isOn: Bool

init(title: String, isOn: Bool) {
    self.title = title
    self.isOn = isOn

    super.init(frame: .zero)
    setupViews()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

let myLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
    label.textColor = .black
    label.textAlignment = .center
    return label
}()

public let mySwitch:UISwitch = {
    let mySwitch = UISwitch()
    mySwitch.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    mySwitch.layer.borderWidth = 0.8
    mySwitch.layer.cornerRadius = 14
    //        mySwitch.tag = num
    return mySwitch
}()

func setupViews() {
    myLabel.text = title
    mySwitch.isOn = isOn
    addSubview(myLabel)
    addSubview(mySwitch)

    myLabel.anchor(top: topAnchor, leading: leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: nil, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    mySwitch.anchor(top: nil, leading: nil, bottom: nil, trailing: trailingAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    mySwitch.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myLabel.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
}

// this is the suggested size for this view
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 350, height: 31)
}
}
```

Parent View:

```
import UIKit

protocol settingDelegate: AnyObject {
    func removeAllFavorites()
    //func activateNotification(isOn: Bool)
    //func allowNotificationAlert(isOn: Bool)
}

class SettingView: UIView {

//MARK: - Properties
var delegate: settingDelegate?
var notifView: UIView?
var alertView: UIView?

let deleteButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
    button.setTitle("Delete Favorite Quotes", for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true // adjust button text to the size
    button.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5 // make it 50% smaller at max
    button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 16, left: 16, bottom: 16, right: 16)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deleteHandler), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority(1000), for: .horizontal)
    return button
}()


//MARK: - Initializers
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    setupViews()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

//MARK: - Helper Methods
func setupViews() {
    backgroundColor = .white

    notifView = RowView(title: "Show day's quote as a notification", isOn: false)
    alertView = RowView(title: "Ring an alert when notification is played", isOn: false)

    guard let notifView = notifView, let alertView = alertView else { return }

    let switchStack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [notifView, alertView])
    switchStack.axis = .vertical // stackVer.axis = .vertical
    switchStack.distribution = .equalCentering
    switchStack.alignment = .leading
    switchStack.spacing = 20

    let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [switchStack, deleteButton])
    stack.axis = .vertical
    stack.distribution = .equalSpacing
    stack.alignment = .center
    stack.spacing = 20

    addSubview(stack)
    stack.anchor(top: safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, leading: leadingAnchor, bottom: safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, trailing: trailingAnchor, paddingTop: 20, paddingLeft: 10, paddingBottom: 20, paddingRight: 10, width: 0, height: 0)
}

@objc func deleteHandler() {
    guard let delegate = delegate else { return }
    delegate.removeAllFavorites()
}

@objc func switchChanged(mySwitch: UISwitch) {
    print("changed")
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 1 delegate and differentiate with a `tag`

```
notifView = RowView(title: "Show day's quote as a notification", isOn: false)
alertView = RowView(title: "Ring an alert when notification is played", isOn: false) 
notifView.tag = 10
alertView.tag = 11
```

--- you can do

```
notifView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.delegate!, action: #selector(self.delegate!.methodClick)))
```